# Node.JS Tibay socket client module

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I'm working on a project that will help to communicate with IoT devices - I called it Tibay.io. I prepared modules and examples for PHP, but I would like to create it for other languages. Now I am working on the NodeJS module and wonder if someone could help me.

I have **module.js** file:

```
const net = require('net');
const tls = require('tls');
module.exports = {
    connect: function(key, pass, protocol) {
        if (!protocol) {
            protocol = 1;
        }
        console.log(key+", "+pass+", "+protocol);
        const socket = tls.connect('api.tibay.io', 12673, () => {
            console.log('Conected!');
        });
    }
}
```

and this is my main (**app.js**) file:

```
var tibay = require('./module.js');
tibay.connect('g1YJxwZrJd4Celsw', 'IpxkSRbDAwiIuDt');
```

I think I can handle connection, but how to add some "on data" events? I think it should looks like:

```
tibay.onData(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: I accidentally commit. Please read it now.

Comment: You should look into how EventEmitter works and how to use it.